# Black screen after install custom kernel

Tags: kernel

am trying install kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ on my notebook HP 455 with dedicated radeon graphics. I have successfully installed a newer kernel. But I got black screen after boot logo ubuntu. I have to press any key several times (15x?) and then desktop shows. I tried Ubuntu 18.04, 18.10, Xubuntu, Mint 19 with same result. Ubuntu 18.10 have native kernel 4.18 and It's work well. But kernel 4.18 in 18.04 doesn't work, same result with 4.16, 4.17, 4.19 and 4.20 RC. I also tried build kernel from source kernel.org, black screen too. Could you please help me? Which log you need for investigation? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use uuku for updating to latest kernal. Run the following commands :

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ukuu

after installing open uuku app and select latest kernal ( 4.19 is latest stable kernal use it and also you can unistall the kernal using same app)

Comment: I've installed latest 4.19.9-041909-generic using ukuu, with same result. Any idea?

Comment: idea in the sense???